# Opscenter not connected to cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have deployed Cassandra cluster(Datastax) in google cloud in multiple regions. When I deployed i checked OpsCenter, it was connected and able to see information. I have restarted (Shutdown and started) the cassandra VM's and OpsCenter, then I checked the OpsCenter. It is showing it is not connected to Cluster.

Check the OpsCenter log file and found the following error message.

**Error Message**

[opscenterd] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred: There are no clusters with name or ID 'Test_Cluster'

**nodetool status**

```
Datacenter: asia-east1-a
========================

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  10.140.0.2  31.07 MB   64           ?       d52bfd45-26e3-4c22-9369-caf5f7aa567a  asia-east1-a

UN  10.140.0.3  31.05 MB   64           ?       35da9f1a-b897-4236-a735-366a6f4e5fa2  asia-east1-a

Datacenter: europe-west1-b
==========================

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  10.132.0.2  212.07 KB  64           ?       0e29e8a5-a94e-4843-8515-4ed1ad751009  europe-west1-b

UN  10.132.0.3  195.63 KB  64           ?       e1b130ad-52e2-4450-88ef-aa7032d93979  europe-west1-b

Datacenter: us-east1-b
======================

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  10.142.0.2  295.4 KB   64           ?       032df12d-f45a-4d57-b6fc-aa4c3f516212  us-east1-b

UN  10.142.0.3  214.28 KB  64           ?       714242e5-4c66-4e90-8816-9328c0c311ff  us-east1-b
```

**Checked Datastax agent**

sudo service datastax-agent status

- DataStax Agent datastax-agent is running

Faced same issue when I tried to deploy new cluster and shutdown and restarted.

Comment: Strange, what happens if you add a new cluster connection?

Comment: Able to add new cluster and able to see ring information but getting the following message when I tried to see the activities.                                      Error loading events: The request to /Test_Cluster/events?count=50&reverse=1 timed out after 10 seconds. If you continue to see this error message, you can workaround this timeout by setting [ui].default_api_timeout to a value larger than 10 in opscenterd.conf and restarting opscenterd. Note that this is a workaround and you should also contact DataStax Support to follow up.

Comment: what version of cassandra? opscenter 5 won't work with c* 2.2 and up. opscenter 6 only works with datastax enterprise. maybe this is your problem?

Comment: The versions are definitely a consideration. See this link for more info: http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html#compatibilityDocument__opsc-compatibility. Could you post some examples of config files? `opscenterd.conf` and `cluster_name.conf` files from the opscenter server and `address.yaml` from the agent of one node. Thank you.